# Crashing while trying to move UITableView rows

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've got some rather complicated rules for moving rows around in a `UITableView`.  There are an undefined number of sections and rows per section, and based on various rules, rows can be moved within or between sections by the user to specific other locations.

All of the data updating and everything is working.  But occasionally, after moving a row, the app will wig out and suddenly there will be an empty space where a row should be displayed.

I'm using:

```
              - (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
```

to specify where the user is allowed to drag the rows based on where the cell is.  98% of the time it works.  But in some cases, when the user is only allowed to drag between sections (can't reorder rows within the section) this error appears, then the app crashes after scrolling over the area with no row.

The exception thrown is pretty useless:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (6) beyond bounds (6)

None of my code is on the stack.  The last UITableView-specific method is

`-[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _visibleCellForGlobalRow:]`

Has anybody seen this issue occur before?  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever solve this Ed?  There is not a answer marked correct and I am seeing the same issues.

Comment: No, I never solved this issue.  I had to loosen the rules governing where a row could be dragged to so that it would not happen

Comment: Are you doing any kind of reload operation (such as reloadData, reloadSections, or reloadRowsAtIndexPath) in your moveRowAtIndexPath method?  I was having the same kind of problem, and I tried to do a reload in a delayed performSelector as suggested by Tom S. below, and it seemed to work, except I put the delay at 1 second to keep iPhone 3.x, 4.x, and the simulator happy.  It is a bit hackish to be sure.

Comment: This may not fix this answer but I found that one must call "reloadData" at the end of "moveRowAtIndexPath" else an internal inconsistency can be raised, especially if you support rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't visited this problem in quite awhile.  The solution I came up with was removing the complicated rules.  Not sure why they allowed usage of complicated rules if it crashed the application when using them.  Not sure if this is fixed in the latest version of the OS or not.

Answer (score 3):

I just hit what I believe is the same problem in my app.

The situation is that I have two table sections. Items can be dragged within and between sections. Users can drag cells to any row in the first section, but in the second section the items are sorted, so for any given cell, there's only one valid row.

If I scroll the view so that the bottom of section 1 and the top of section 2 are visible, grab an item in section 1 that sorts to the bottom of section 2, and drag it into the the top of section 2, my `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:` method gets called and I return the correct destination position, which is several rows below the bottom of the screen. In the UI, you can see an empty cell gets created at the bottom of the screen, which is not the correct destination row.

When you let go of the cell, that bogus cell that was created at the bottom of the screen (in the middle of section 2) stays there! `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` never even gets called for it. As soon as you try to do anything with that cell, you crash.

My first solution was to just call [tableView reloadData] at the end of `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`. But that causes a crash, so instead I call it indirectly after a delay. But then there's **another** bug: after the delayed reloadData call, `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` gets called again with a bogus request to move an item one past the end of the first section to that same position. So, I had to add code to ignore bogus no-op requests.

So, here's the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)pathSrc toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)pathDst
{
  // APPLE_BUG: after doing the delayed table reload (see below), we get a bogus
  // request to move a nonexistant cell to its current location
  if (pathSrc.row == pathDst.row && pathSrc.section == pathDst.section)
    return;

  // update your data model to reflect the move...

  // APPLE_BUG: if you move a cell to a row that's off-screen (because the destination
  // has been modified), the bogus cell gets created and eventually will cause a crash
  [self performSelector:@selector(delayedReloadData:) withObject:tableView afterDelay:0];
}

- (void)delayedReloadData:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  Assert(tableView == self.tableView);
  [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Note that there's still a UI bug. On the screen, the dragged cell gets animated into the bogus empty cell. At the end of the animation, the empty cell gets redrawn with the correct data for that row, but the observant user will notice the dragged cell getting animated to the wrong spot then instantly morphed to a different cell.

This is definitely a goofy UI. I considered scrolling the proper destination row onto the screen, but if I were to do that it would fill the screen with section two and then any attempt to drag back to section one would be continually thwarted by my (now annoying) autoscrolling. I may have to change the UI, but that would require some complex and bothersome changes to my data model.

Comment: I'm glad at least one other person has had the same experience as me!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like something somewhere is requesting element 6 from an array that only has elements at indexes `0-5` (meaning 6 elements).

This usually happens when the code tries to do:

```
NSUInteger index = [somearray count];
id obj = [somearray objectAtIndex:index];
```

because `count` is upper boundary and arrays start from 0 the last element is at `count - 1`.

This might not be directly in your code but you may be restricting something to a number of elements and then requesting one past the last element.

Comment: Note that one should use `NSUInteger` for the result of `count`, lest it be truncated (particularly when moving code to the Mac, where `NSUInteger` is, increasingly often, larger than an `int`). It's also important to keep it unsigned so that comparisons to this never-negative value always make sense.

Comment: I am aware of the base problem, but that code that's accessing the array is deep within the framework.  Like I said, there's absolutely no code of my own on the stack at the time of the crash.  At its base, it seems like a bug in the UITableView object.

Comment: I had a similar issue, because i used `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`'s return value, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error with deleting that I couldn't figure out for a while -- but I put `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]` around the code and it fixed everything. Could be that your datasource just isn't updating before it attempts to redraw, and those methods should prevent that (worth a shot, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Are you updating your data model for the table in `targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath`

Or in the DataSource delegate method: `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` ?

Taken from the Table View Programming Guide for iPhone OS, under reordering table cells:

> The table view sends
>   **tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:**
>   to its data source (if it implements
>   the method). *In this method the data
>   source updates the data-model array
>   that is the source of items for the
>   table view, moving the item to a
>   different location in the array*.

And for the delegate method, it is written:

> Every time the dragged row is over a
>   destination, the table view sends
>   **tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:**
>   to its delegate (if it implements the
>   method). In this method the delegate
>   may reject the current destination for
>   the dragged row and specify an
>   alternative one.

`tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:` is for determining whether a relocation is allowed, but actual changes to your data model should take place in  `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`

Perhaps this is what you're doing, but I can't tell just from the info you provided.

Comment: No, I'm updating it in the moveRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 1):

Here Cityarray is an array...

```
   id obj =[Cityarray objectatindex:sourceindexpath.row];
        [Cityarray removeObjectatindex:(sourceindexpath.row)];
        [Cityarray insertObject:obj atindex:destinationindexpath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

I just happen to witness this problem. However, my version of crash seems to occur on an iOS 3.0 device that I'm trying to support, and I have only two rows in the table that I'm trying to rearrange. I ran the app again with the same code on another device with iOS 4.0 and that bug seems to have been fixed.

I'm still researching this, but as of now, I'm disabling moving of rows on devices with iOS 3.0 until a fix is found.