# How to stop UITableView moveRowAtIndexPath from leaving blank rows upon reordering

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, crash

I am having an issue where in reordering my UITableViewCells, the tableView is not scrolling with the cell.  Only a blank row appears and any subsequent scrolling gets an Array out of bounds error without any of my code in the Stack Trace.  [Here is a quick video of the problem.](http://www.screencast.com/users/coneybeare/folders/Jing/media/642ebe77-c6d0-4e63-818e-72282581a0f7)

Here is the relevant code:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return indexPath.section == 1;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BOOL ret = indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row < self.count;
    DebugLog(@"canMoveRowAtIndexPath: %d:%d %@", indexPath.section, indexPath.row, (ret ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
    return ret;
}
- (void)delayedUpdateCellBackgroundPositionsForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateCellBackgroundPositionsForTableView:) withObject:tableView waitUntilDone:NO];
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    if (fromIndexPath.row == toIndexPath.row) return;

    DebugLog(@"Moved audio from %d:%d to %d:%d", fromIndexPath.section, fromIndexPath.row, toIndexPath.section, toIndexPath.row);
    NSMutableArray *audio = [self.items objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.section];
    [audio exchangeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row withObjectAtIndex:toIndexPath.row];
    [self performSelector:@selector(delayedUpdateCellBackgroundPositionsForTableView:) withObject:tableView afterDelay:kDefaultAnimationDuration/3];
}
```

And here is the generated Stack Trace of the crash:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
iPhone Simulator 3.2 (193.3), iPhone OS 3.0 (7A341)
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray removeObjectsInRange:]: index (6) beyond bounds (6)'

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   CoreFoundation                  0x302ac924 ___TERMINATING_DUE_TO_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION___ + 4
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x93cb2509 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3028e5fb +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 155
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3028e55a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
4   Foundation                      0x305684e9 _NSArrayRaiseBoundException + 121
5   Foundation                      0x30553a6e -[NSCFArray removeObjectsInRange:] + 142
6   UIKit                           0x30950105 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow] + 862
7   UIKit                           0x30947715 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 250
8   QuartzCore                      0x0090bd94 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 78
9   QuartzCore                      0x0090bb55 CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 229
10  QuartzCore                      0x0090b3ae CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 302
11  QuartzCore                      0x0090b022 CA::Transaction::commit() + 292
12  QuartzCore                      0x009132e0 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 84
13  CoreFoundation                  0x30245c32 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 594
14  CoreFoundation                  0x3024503f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 2575
15  CoreFoundation                  0x30244628 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 88
16  GraphicsServices                0x32044c31 GSEventRunModal + 217
17  GraphicsServices                0x32044cf6 GSEventRun + 115
18  UIKit                           0x309021ee UIApplicationMain + 1157
19  XXXXXXXX                        0x0000278a main + 104 (main.m:12)
20  XXXXXXXX                        0x000026f6 start + 54
```

NOte that the array out of bounds length is not the length of my elements (I have 9), but always something smaller.

I have been trying to solve this for many <strike>hours</strike> days without avail… any ideas?

---

UPDATE: More code as requested

In my delegate:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath {
    int count = [(UAPlaylistEditDataSource *)self.dataSource count];
    if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.section == 0) {
        return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:sourceIndexPath.section];
    }else if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.row >= count) {
        return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count-1 inSection:sourceIndexPath.section];
    }
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}
```

…thats about it.  I am using the three20 framework and I have not had any issues with reordering till now.  The problem is also not in the `updateCellBackgroundPositionsForTableView:` method as it still crashes when this is commented out.

Comment: Can you tell which line is causing crash?
Provide call stack when crash is occured.
Are you sure, that it's no connected with your updateCellBackgroundPositionsForTableView method?

Comment: The stack trace does not contain any of my code (not to say I am not causing it) but there is no useful information in there in regards to lines of code.  I will update the stacktrace above anyway

Comment: Can you add the code for
updateCellBackgroundPositionsForTableView ?
And other UITableViewDataSource-related methods?
I have another suggestion.
I think you have problem with creating/reusing cells... Need more code... more code... :)

Comment: I don't have much more code for you to see… I am using the excellent three20 framework. Also, the crash is definitely not in the updateCellBackgroundPositionsForTableView method as it still crashes when this is commented out.

Comment: I've added all your methods in my project and all works fine.
Problem is in another methods of this dataSource. or Maybe in TableViewDelegate.

Comment: Nope. D'you think it's Three20-related? I can try to use it :) Which component are you using from Three20?

Comment: three20 is an entire framework, full of subclasses for almost every UI class.  Thus, I am using all components.  The section of the app is a standard TTTableViewController with a local TTSectionedDataSource.  It is pretty stable and used by many apps, so I don't think the problem is there although it certainly could be.  I could not duplicate it in the default ttcatalog app.

Comment: I've duplicated your issue :)
Working on it.

Comment: Are you sure that' you've added your TableViewDelegate ? 
- (id<UITableViewDelegate>)createDelegate {
  return [[[MyTableViewDelegate alloc] initWithController:self] autorelease];
}

Comment: This really isnt the place for us to be going back and forth like this.  you can AIM or SKYPE me at "coneybeare" and I will be happy to answer any questions you have.  And as an incentinve to anybody else reading this, I am going to be offering a BIG bounty for this in a few hours once my question is 48hours old :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO... Actually problem is in Three20 framework.
TTTableView, which is subclass of UITableView have two buggy methods:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// UIScrollView

- (void)setContentSize:(CGSize)size {
  if (_contentOrigin) {
    CGFloat minHeight = self.height + _contentOrigin;
    if (size.height < minHeight) {
      size.height = self.height + _contentOrigin;
    }
  }

  CGFloat y = self.contentOffset.y;
  [super setContentSize:size];

  if (_contentOrigin) {
    // As described below in setContentOffset, UITableView insists on messing with the 
    // content offset sometimes when you change the content size or the height of the table
    self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, y);
  }
}

- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)point {
  // UITableView (and UIScrollView) are really stupid about resetting the content offset
  // when the table view itself is resized.  There are times when I scroll to a point and then
  // disable scrolling, and I don't want the table view scrolling somewhere else just because
  // it was resized.  
  if (self.scrollEnabled) {
    if (!(_contentOrigin && self.contentOffset.y == _contentOrigin && point.y == 0)) {
      [super setContentOffset:point];
    }
  }
}
```

Just comment them, And all will works fine.
I don't know if this will destroy something somewhere, but at least, you know where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks!  I have actually isolated it even further with your guidance.  The problem is that when reordering the row, self.scrollEnabled is NO so the super line is not called.  I am going to have to look into why this was done (I'm sure it had a reason) but it might be so obscure that I can change it back.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-posting my answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884491/crashing-while-trying-to-move-uitableview-rows):

I just hit what I believe is the same problem in my app.

The situation is that I have two table sections. Items can be dragged within and between sections. Users can drag cells to any row in the first section, but in the second section the items are sorted, so for any given cell, there's only one valid row.

If I scroll the view so that the bottom of section 1 and the top of section 2 are visible, grab an item in section 1 that sorts to the bottom of section 2, and drag it into the the top of section 2, my `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:` method gets called and I return the correct destination position, which is several rows below the bottom of the screen. In the UI, you can see an empty cell gets created at the bottom of the screen, which is not the correct destination row.

When you let go of the cell, that bogus cell that was created at the bottom of the screen (in the middle of section 2) stays there! `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` never even gets called for it. As soon as you try to do anything with that cell, you crash.

My first solution was to just call [tableView reloadData] at the end of `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`. But that causes a crash, so instead I call it indirectly after a delay. But then there's **another** bug: after the delayed reloadData call, `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` gets called again with a bogus request to move an item one past the end of the first section to that same position. So, I had to add code to ignore bogus no-op requests.

So, here's the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)pathSrc toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)pathDst
{
  // APPLE_BUG: after doing the delayed table reload (see below), we get a bogus
  // request to move a nonexistant cell to its current location
  if (pathSrc.row == pathDst.row && pathSrc.section == pathDst.section)
    return;

  // update your data model to reflect the move...

  // APPLE_BUG: if you move a cell to a row that's off-screen (because the destination
  // has been modified), the bogus cell gets created and eventually will cause a crash
  [self performSelector:@selector(delayedReloadData:) withObject:tableView afterDelay:0];
}

- (void)delayedReloadData:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  Assert(tableView == self.tableView);
  [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Note that there's still a UI bug. On the screen, the dragged cell gets animated into the bogus empty cell. At the end of the animation, the empty cell gets redrawn with the correct data for that row, but the observant user will notice the dragged cell getting animated to the wrong spot then instantly morphed to a different cell.

This is definitely a goofy UI. I considered scrolling the proper destination row onto the screen, but if I were to do that it would fill the screen with section two and then any attempt to drag back to section one would be continually thwarted by my (now annoying) autoscrolling. I may have to change the UI, but that would require some complex and bothersome changes to my data model.

Comment: Hallo Tom!

You actually solved my problem!
For detailed information see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014906/reranging-a-uitableview

Thank you very much!