# Reranging a uitableview

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I ran into the same problem as desciped in: [Crashing while trying to move UITableView rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884491/crashing-while-trying-to-move-uitableview-rows)!
All I want to do is on specific reranging operations insert a new cell or delete the selected one.

Sometimes I get:

> ********* Assertion failure in -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimationForReorderingRow], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-963.10/UITableViewSupport.m:295 Attempt to
>   create two animations for cell exception

and when I want to reload my data by calling `[self.tableView reloadData]`
I get:

> ********** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)'

Is there anybody out there who knows how to handle this problem?

Comment: Same problem as....? Without code hard to tell. Maybe use the debugger and look at the stack trace where it crashes. Can be anything from not delivering cells, to memory mis-management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hallo again!

Thanks for all your help!
I actually found a solution for my problem!

I don't care about animating the tableview while editing anymore!
I finally found a solution in this post: [How to stop UITableView moveRowAtIndexPath from leaving blank rows upon reordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242387/how-to-stop-uitableview-moverowatindexpath-from-leaving-blank-rows-upon-reorderin/3021063#3021063)

Tom Saxton said:

> // APPLE_BUG: if you move a cell to a row that's off-screen (because the destination
>     // has been modified), the bogus cell gets created and eventually will cause a crash

So my code looks like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
if( fromIndexPath == toIndexPath ) {
    return;
}

if (toIndexPath.row == [self.data count] -1) { //element has been dragged to the bottom
        self.data removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
        [self performSelector:@selector(delayedReloadData:) withObject:tableView afterDelay:0];
}
else { //Normal reoder operation
        [self.data removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
     [self.data insertObject:element atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
}
```

}

```
- (void)delayedReloadData:(UITableView *)tableView {
//Assert(tableView == self.tableView);
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

I also had a mem leak in my initData method, which I solved like this:

```
-(void) initData {
if (!self.data) {
    self.data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
else {
    [self.data removeAllObjects];
}

[self.data addObjectsFromArray:[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]];
```

}

Thanks for all your help!

Nikolay

Answer (score 0):

You still have a mem leak in initData.  I assume you defined your data as "@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *data".  So when you call alloc/init the retain count is 1, and then you assign to self.data which does a retain, giving it a count of 2.  You need to do:

```
NSMutableArray *ary = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.data = ary;
[ary release];
```